# What does the dollar curly brackets ${} mean in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, jsp-tags

What does `${}` means in JSP? For example,

```html
<c:if test="${!empty cookie.lang}">
    <fmt:setLocale value="${cookie.lang.value}" />
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 24):

It is an [EL expression](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) basically it outputs the value that result from evaluating the expression, to put it simply, it allows you to access the values of the properties of your [Java beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) using  "dots" instead of using getters and setters, using it you can access instances of beans that can be in session, request, or page scope.

Answer (score 11):

It is Expression Language. Before EL evolved, the same purpose was achieved by using scriptlets `<%=..%>`The primary purpose of using this syntax is to avoid scriptlets in jsp. Scriptlets and the enclosed java code is considered bad practise because jsps are not 'supposed' to have java code. At least that is the theory.

Answer (score 4):

The `${}` referes to [EL expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html). You usually access some managed beans on the server via the EL expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed an Expression Language expression. A great resource is the [el](/questions/tagged/el) tag on this site, especially the [Expression Language wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) is a must read in my opinion.