# What does it mean by ${ } dollor and brackets in jsp?

Tags: jsp, el

I saw this in jsp file, guessed it brought something in.
Where does this come from? DB? another source of jsp file? or some scripts?

Comment: Duplicate of [What does ${} means in jsp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736842/what-does-means-in-jsp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `${}` is  a symbol for **Java Expression Language**

you can check the documentation at [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.htmlNWL3r3-CwvKbZQ&bvm=bv.69837884,d.dGc)

quote from Oracle :

> EL can :
>
> - Dynamically read application data stored in JavaBeans components, various data structures, and implicit objects
> - Dynamically write data, such as user input into forms, to JavaBeans components
> - Invoke arbitrary static and public methods
> - Dynamically perform arithmetic operations

Answer (score 1):

This is the Java Expression Language, you can check more info and examples about it in this tag [page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)